# Nodejs not receiving POST body

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm sending a POST in angularjs like so:

```
$http.post("/mypath", { data: "foobar" })
```

And in nodejs (expressjs) I'm trying to pick it up like so:

```
app.post "/mypath", (req, res) ->
  console.log "req.body: ", req.body
  res.end()
```

I've tried various different incarnations (`body: "foobar"`, etc), but I keep getting `req.body: undefined`

Is there a simple way to read the payload in node/express?

Comment: Are you using the body parser anywhere? You don't show the rest of the relevant config.

Comment: @DaveNewton I wasn't.  Seems like it should be built into express, but I suppose building up from basic functionality is better than bloatware.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get data from a POST in Node, you need to use a body Parser. eg:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//use bodyParser() to let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: I tried that but I'm still getting `{}` as the body. Why?